# How to change "User cannot change password'' with powershell for all users

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

All of my user in AD have no permition to change their password and I want to change it. How can I change it via PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly want to do for **every** user, it can be done with just a couple lines

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter *
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -CannotChangePassword $false
}
```